# How can I code a solid Map-Scrolling system for a C# 2D game?

Tags: c#

As you may have seen from my previous questions, I'm trying to code a little 2D game for fun. I'm now facing a problem that I can't solve and I need help to figure out how to do this.

I'm going to generate a map by splitting the screen into little chunks. Each chunk is about 20*20 big and has got one represanting image, e.g. a greenish surface for grass or a greyish one for stone. A level should be bigger than the screen, so I decided on using the following scheme:
The map is x wide and y high. The chunks in my level will look like a square. For understanding, I'll try to visualize it to you:

```
<----------------x---------------->
|| || || || || || || || || || || ||    ^
                                       |
|| || || || || || || || || || || ||    |
                                       |
|| || || || || || || || || || || ||    |
                                       |
|| || || || || || || || || || || ||    |
                                       |
|| || || || || || || || || || || ||    y
                                       |
|| || || || || || || || || || || ||    |
                                       |
|| || || || || || || || || || || ||    |
                                       |
|| || || || || || || || || || || ||    |
                                       |
|| || || || || || || || || || || ||    ↓
```

For drawing and managing these chunks, I created a class holding information about each of them seperatly. Each one has got an ID which is converted to a skin later, so I've got that going. My problem is, that the screen is supposed not to display this whole field, but only a piece of it. If the player moves over the e.g. right border, the form should show one chunk more of x on the *right*, therefor one less chunk of x on the *left*. Like a simple side scrolling game, but with 4 directions instead of two (N/E/S/W instead of E/W).

To make it easy to save the map, I wanted to assign one identifier (e.g. a number) to each field. It would look something like that:

```
<----------------x---------------->
|1|  |2|  |3|  |4|  |5|  |6|  |7|  |8|  |9|  |10| |11| |12|  ^
                                                             |
|13| |14| |15| |16| |17| |18| |19| |20| |21| |22| |23| |24|  |
                                                             |
|25| |26| |27| |28| |29| |30| |31| |32| |33| |34| |35| |36|  |
   **Just imagine continuing this all over the map**         |
|| || || || || || || || || || || ||                          |
                                                             |
|| || || || || || || || || || || ||                          y
                                                             |
|| || || || || || || || || || || ||                          |
                                                             |
|| || || || || || || || || || || ||                          |
                                                             |
|| || || || || || || || || || || ||                          |
                                                             |
|| || || || || || || || || || || ||                          ↓
```

In theory, I got this and know what to do, but if I try to actually program this, I get stuck. Does anybody know how to efficently do this?

Any suggestions on how to improve this system are welcome, too!

Thanks alot and please appreciate the time it has taken me to write the example pictures. I really tried to clear up what I mean!

Comment: Upvoted for the effort, even though the question is rather simple. I think I speak for a lot of people when I say that we do appreciate it. When people put even a modicum of effort into their posts, they stand out because so few people do.

Comment: I know that this question is simple for someone who learned this, but my school doesn't teach any IT until you reach a high year.. And well, that's why I gotta learn everything from scratch, allone. But thanks for the appreciation!

Comment: Are you looking for help in storing the chunks that make up your map or help in deciding which chunks need to be displayed?

Comment: I'm afraid I need help with both..